# How can I create a style that will ONLY switch off spell-check

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

As a developer I often wish to paste code into my documents. Modern IDE's also provide copy/paste facilities to also copy the syntax highlighting. Sadly Word then chooses to spell-check the code with the obvious results.

I would like to be able to apply a style that ONLY changes the spell checking of the pasted multi-coloured code.

I have created a style called `Code` whose summary reads just:

> *Do not check spelling or grammar, English (United Kingdom), Style: Show in the Styles gallery, Priority: 2*

Sadly this also changes the font and removes all colouring.

I want to be able to apply a style that:

1. Changes the text to *Do not check spelling or grammar*
2. Does NOT change anything else. Not the font, not any of the colouring, nothing.

Is this possible?

For now I have added `Set Proofing Language...` to my Quick-Access bar giving me a 3-click solution. I would much prefer a one-click option.

I would be fairly happy with a script in VBA that I can expose under a button but I would much rather use a style.